# How can I obtain a recovery DVD for a Toshiba notebook, sold in Europe?

Tags: toshiba-laptop

Our Toshiba notebook, bought (I think) 2015 doesn't start anymore, or rather starts into a myriad of recovery options. Recovering the system without external media does not work (we tried all options except complete reinstall). According to some sources, one can - or could, once upon a time - download an image for a recovery DVD or buy one from Toshiba. However, when hunting around the Toshiba homepage, I only found links to external service partners. 69€ for a reinstall may not be the worst option, but maybe there'S a better one.

The notebook is a PSKUQE-01100WGR

Is there any way to get an image for a Toshiba recovery DVD?

Comment: Ask Toshiba?...

Comment: As I wrote in my question, Toshiba no longer provides images. That doesn't mean no one else provides them. I *can* reword the question to "how to repair my notebook" but theres no option withoput recovery medium left ...

Comment: @DavidPostill in your opinion is there any chance to reopen this question? as said I can reword to follow the template linked above, but it will remain a question for the specific recovery disk.

Comment: You can download the ISO for Windows 8 or 10 directly from Microsoft (and preferably burn a USB, do not use DVDs). That is the recovery media. If needed, reinstall the drivers from Toshiba's websute. That's all.

Comment: Recovery CDs for many brands and older models of laptops are available on sites like eBay.  They're usually specific to the brand & model. I found 2 offers in the UK for appropriate Windows recovery disks, by searching ebay for "toshiba recovery disk l50".  Also I can't tell from the question if this is one of those laptops that allows a complete re-install from a recovery partition on the disk - does it offer that option and, if so, why not use it?

Comment: It does allow the option of reinstall from recovery partition, however it doesnt work (I don't recall the exact error message and if there was an error code given or)

Comment: Windows offers (Windows 7, Windows 8, and Windows 10) ISOs for free, purchasing a recovery disk, is not necessary.  Any drivers that might have existed on the Toshiba disk, can be downloaded, from Windows Update and/or Toshiba website for the product.  **Don't waste your money on something that is free.**